# PHP XPath issue for amazon products

Tags: php, regex, xpath

I would like get all the images from following URL and using following Xpath Query but ever time query return null.

URL:

```
http://www.amazon.com/gp/browse.html?ie=UTF8&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&me=A219HML0CVO0HP
```

Xpath Query:

```
$products = $xpath->evaluate('//div[@class="productTitle"]//img');
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have one too many forward slashes before img:

```
$xpath->evaluate('//div[@class="productTitle"]/img');
```

This should match the following HTML that is present in that link:

```
<div id="srProductTitle_B0000CBIFG_0" class="productTitle">
    <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0000CBIFG" rel="nofollow noreferrer">
    <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51BZs4Gf5pL._SL160_AA160_.jpg" class="" border="0" alt="Product Details"  width="160" height="160"/><br clear="all" />Weed Eater 952701594 0.065-Inch-by-200-Foot Bulk Round String Trimmer Line
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I replaces with single forward slashes but still i am getting null values.

Comment: You are right, It should match but it is not matching i am not figure out the issue...

Comment: Thanks for your reply again, Do you any idea how to resove this html error.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you...

```
$subject = file_get_contents('http://www.amazon.com/gp/browse.html?ie=UTF8&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&me=A219HML0CVO0HP');
$string = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $subject);

preg_match_all('/<a(.*?)href="(.*?)">(.*?)<img(.*?)src="(.*?)"(.*?)class=""(.*?)border="0"(.*?)alt="Product(.*?)Details/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $result[5][$i];
}
```

**Thanks.....p2c**